# How to make a few webpages display different on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, mobile-browser

I have a webpage that is quite wide and short on about 3 pages, the pages that are wide and long display fine on a mobile phone browser, but the pages that are short show up on only less than half the screen.

Is there anyway I can make a seperate page for each of those 3 pages and have them come up only when someone is using a mobile phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert some JavaScript that will sniff out the User Agent (web browser & version) on each page.  Here is a link that explains how to do this:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Once you have done that, then swap your CSS file for that page to the one appropriate for the device, or redirect to a special HTML page for that device.

Comment: Sniffing user agents is the wrong way to go and has fallen out of favor for many years. There is no guarantee the browser is identifying itself correctly and no guarantee javascript functions are available. You still must test for functionality. But all of that is mostly unnecessary if media queries can do the job.

Comment: Wow, really?  Tell that to bluenile.com whose html 5 mobile app I coded.  They are a quite large online company. Publicly traded and notorious for their rigid QA process.  It seems that my approach suited them. . .

Comment: Discuss it with Microsoft's Eric Law: The Perils of User-Agent Sniffing http://goo.gl/3oS3A

Answer (score 0):

If you search Google for 'Responsive Design', there is lots of advice on how to use the same page, but make it appear differently on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Along with "[responsive design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)" you should investigate "[media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)" which will allow you to adjust your CSS and help align the elements to the display size of each device viewing it. No javascript necessary.
[How to use Media Queries in Mobile](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: Rob--This your answer is helpful, but not comprehensive.  Cheers for your effort, but it was nasty of you to downvote my answer.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Sorry you feel that way but your answer is poor. See my comment (which I forgot to add).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - You may have read my post before I added some links. This is a fairly comprehensive subject that requires more time to spell out here.

Comment: "See my comment (which I forgot to add)". . .sure Rob.  Just don't forget that the mission of this site is for developers to help developers, not to just boost your own score.  Honestly, I don't really care about the 2 points, I just think that it was against the spirit of this site for you to do it and that annoys me.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Then you misunderstand. I lose points when I downvote, too.

Comment: Seriously, is that how it works? If so, then genuinely, I apologize.  I guess that would mean that you have the best interest of the person asking the question at heart.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have stated. Responsive web design with Media Queries is best. Check out these sites.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/
http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/